# MATLAB: Checking type of table

Tags: variables, matlab

I want to ask how to check if a variable is table 1x8 or 8x1 of type logical?
I know I can check the class of an array for logical like this:

```
strcmp(class(a),'logical')
```

I know I can get the size of table like this:

```
[h w] = size(a);
if(w==1 & h==8 | w==8 & h==1)
```

But what if table has more than 2 dimensions? How can I get number of dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of dimensions, use [`ndims`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ndims.html)

```
numDimensions = ndims(a);
```

However, you can instead request `size` to return a single output, which is an array `[sizeX,sizeY,sizeZ,...]`, and check its length. Even better, you can use [`isvector`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isvector.html) to test whether it's a 1-d array.

So you can write

```
if isvector(a) && length(a) == 8
disp('it''s a 1x8 or 8x1 array')
end
```

Finally, to test for logical, it's easier to write

```
islogical(a)
```

Comment: Oh! Thanx! I was guessing dims(a) but there is no such function.

Comment: @Miko Kronn: Have a look at my edit for a possibly even better solution to your problem

Comment: Thanx again :-). Is there difference between & and && in Matlab?

Comment: @Miko Kronn: `&&` works only for scalar logicals (i.e. no comparing of entire arrays). However, if you combine multiple tests, it will start with the first and only evaluate as long as the result of a further test has a chance to influence the result. I.e. with `&&`, if the first statement is false, there's no point in checking anything else.